# Seeking function to model the curve of solutions to $x^y = y^x$

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I found a graph of the solutions to the equation $x^y = y^x$ online; the one who posted the graph was curious as to why the set of solutions formed a line and a curve that intersect at the point $(e,e)$.
The line of solutions is easy to understand - it is the line $y = x$. Finding an equation for the curve is a bit more aggravating.

To start, we manipulate the equation $x^y = y^x$ until we obtain
$$\frac{y}{x} = \frac{\ln{y}}{\ln{x}}$$
To make things a little simpler, we concern ourselves with the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and define $C = \frac{y}{x}$, noting that $C > 0$. This yields the pair of equations
$$ y = Cx$$
$$ y = x^C$$
With some simple manipulations, we find
$$x = C^{\frac{1}{C-1}}$$
$$y = C^{\frac{C}{C-1}}$$
There is a slight reason for worry when $C = 1$, but we recall
$$\lim_{C\to1} C^{\frac{1}{C-1}} = \lim_{C\to1} C^{\frac{C}{C-1}} = e$$
which is exactly what we want.
In summary, for any given $C \in \mathbb{R}^+\setminus\{1\}$ we can find a point on the curve (under our restriction).

Unfortunately, I was not able to go much further. Is there a function that models the curve of solutions to $x^y = y^x$, i.e. the set
$$S = \left\{\left(C^{\frac{1}{C-1}},C^{\frac{C}{C-1}}\right) : C \in \mathbb{R}^+\setminus\{1\}\right\} \cup \{(e,e)\}$$
If so, how do we derive it?

Comment: Is there a function? Yes, there is (from $(1, \infty)$ to itself). Is there a nice expression for that function? Well, that's what you're really asking, isn't it? I don't think there is one, but I'd be impressed if anyone manages to find one. Also, I think you mean $S = \cdots \cup \{(e,e)\}$

Comment: Haha, I suppose by providing $S$ I've technically given a function. But you're right, I'm really asking for a nice(er) expression for that function. I've made a correction to the mistake you pointed out, too.